# Trabalhar com listas sem ser usando Array() em PHP

Tags: php, array, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Sei que no PHP pra quase todo tipo de lista, trabalhamos com `Array()`, mas seria esta a única forma de trabalhar com listas em PHP?

Existe alguma outra forma de trabalhar com listas de objetos em PHP, parecido com as classes do Collections (`List`, `Map`, etc)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sim, existe no PHP algumas classes padrões (da SPL- Standard PHP Library) que fazem muito bem esse trabalho.

Geralmente essas classes implementam as interfaces `ArrayAccess`, `Iterator` ou `IteratorAggregate`.

A interface `ArrayAccess` permite acesso e definição de membros da classe como se fosse um `array`.

Eis alguns exemplos:

## SplStack

Essa classe funciona como uma pilha. Quando você adiciona um elemento via `SplStack $stack[]`, ao invés de adicionar o elemento no final como se faz num array comum,  ele adiciona ao início.

Exemplo:

```
$stack = new SplStack;

$stack[] = 1;

$stack[] = 2;

$stack[] = 3;

print_r(iterator_to_array($stack));
```

Isso retornaria:

```
[
     2 => 3,
     1 => 2,
     0 => 1,
 ]
```

## SplFixedArray

A classe `SplFixedArray` é utilizada para determinar um número fixo de elementos para um `array`. Você determina na instância qual é o número de elementos que estarão presentes nessa estrutura. É semelhante ao `Array` do javascript, já que você não pode nomear os índices, mas os índices são apenas numéricos. Se você tentar colocar um tamanho maior que o esperado, uma exceção será lançada.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = new SplFixedArray(3);

$arr[0] = 0;

$arr[1] = 1;

$arr[2] = 2;
```

Algumas pessoas dizem que fizeram testes e obtiveram uma economia 33% vezes menor que um `array` comum, mas esse é o tipo de coisas que não costumo me focar.

## SplObjectStorage

Essa classe serve para você armazenar objetos. A grande diferença dela é que, quando você define um objeto nela, o mesmo é passado como índice dessa "estrutura".

```
 $s = new SplObjectStorage();

$o1 = new StdClass;
$o2 = new StdClass;
$o3 = new StdClass;

$s[$o1] = "data for object 1";
$s[$o2] = array(1,2,3);
```

Esses são alguns exemplos, mas existem outros, que já foram citadas pelo @rray.

Comment: Me pergunto pq tem um exemplo da SPLStack .... :D

Comment: Acho que entendi sua piada @rray :D

Comment: As respostas do rray e bigown são excelentes, mas você exemplificou o uso de algumas das possibilidades.

Answer (score 16):

A partir do php 7.2 foi disponibilizada uma nova [extensão](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ds.php) para se trabalhar com estutura de dados mais rígidas. Os tipos existentes são:

- Hashable
- Sequence
- Vector
- Deque
- Map
- Pair
- Set
- Stack
- Queue
- PriorityQueue

Sim existem outras estruturas de dados além do padrão `Array()`, elas estão na biblioteca [SPL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php), que vem por padrão desde o PHP5.0.

Alguns tipos são:

- SplStack
- SplQueue
- SplHeap
- SplMaxHeap
- SplMinHeap
- SplPriorityQueue
- SplFixedArray
- SplObjectStorage

Comment: Ah, rapaz! Mal vi seus movimentos :D

Answer (score 7):

Por padrão não existe. Nada impede de você criar tipos novos que implemente especificamente cada uma destas estruturas e algoritmos relacionados. Provavelmente usando o *array* concretamente dentro da estrutura.

Também pode usar alguma biblioteca que já implemente isto para você, como o caso da citada pelo rray (que parece ser bem ruim, por sinal :P) que é uma extensão.

Em tese também é possível implementar alguma estrutura em C e expô-la ao PHP, mas quase ninguém faz isto, teria uma vantagem de performance bastante interessante.

[Algumas pessoas já fizeram isto](https://medium.com/@rtheunissen/efficient-data-structures-for-php-7-9dda7af674cd#.xifu5lokf), já que eles também consideraram a SPL uma porcaria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Queria saber o que está errado.

Comment: Não entendi também o -1.

Comment: Deve ser porque eu disse que a biblioteca parece ser ruim. A pessoa deve achar que ela é ótima. Por isso "todo mundo está usando em seus códigos".

Comment: É tão boa que em boa parte das páginas tem explicação das funções e recursos que você não pode usar por causa dos bugs :)

Comment: Mas pelo jeito o povo gostou dela assim mesmo :D